# Probability using combinatorics: probability doesn't sum to 1

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> In a certain lottery, 10,000 tickets are sold and 10 prizes are awarded. What is the probability of **not** getting a prize if you buy 2 tickets.

The answer to this question is simple enough:  $$ \frac {9990 \choose 2}{10000 \choose 2} $$
I understand this answer, since there are 2 ways of picking from the 9990 tickets that don't give you a ticket. And 2 ways of picking *some* ticket from the 10,000 tickets. But, I wanted to verify this by calculating the probability of **getting** a ticket.

I used a similar method:

$$ \frac{10 \choose 2}{10000 \choose 2} $$

However, when I use a calculator to add them up, they don't sum to **1.** I repeated this exercise for buying 10 tickets, in which case the answers for not getting a ticket and getting a ticket were respectively:

$$ \frac {9990 \choose 10}{10000 \choose 10} $$
$$ \frac{10 \choose 10}{10000 \choose 10} $$

In this case as well, the probability don't sum to 1. I understand that I'm actually decreasing the numerator in the second case. But I can't understand intuitively why this is wrong.

While calculating the probability of not getting a ticket, we divide the number of ways we can pick a ticket that doesn't give you a prize by the number of ways you can pick any ticket. So, while calculuating the probability of getting a ticket, shouldn't we divide the number of ways we can pick a ticket that gives you a prize divided the total number of ways you can pick a ticket?

Comment: These are good questions to ask. What if you buy $20$ tickets; what are the outcomes and their probabilities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $\frac{\binom{10}{2}}{\binom{10000}{2}}$ is the probability of getting **two** prizes! Hence, you are missing the case where you get just one price. If you add that, you do indeed get $1$:

$$
\frac{\binom{9990}{2}}{\binom{10000}{2}}
+\frac{\binom{10}{2}}{\binom{10000}{2}}
+\frac{\binom{9990}{1}\cdot\binom{10}{1}}{\binom{10000}{2}}
= 1.
$$

Comment: Shouldn't you also show the correct probability for winning at least one prize?

Comment: Winning at least one prize is the same as winning exactly one or exactly two prices, so the last two summands.

Comment: Wow, that was really useful! I also used this logic to answer the question posed by @David in the comments, and they summed to 1 as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve by Binomial as the numbers are large.  Hypergeometric distribution used by @Christoph gives the exact probabilities:

Probability that you will get a prize $= \frac{1}{1000}$

probability that you will not get a prize $= \frac{999}{1000}$

If you buy two tickets, the probability that you will not get a prize is

$\approx {2\choose0}(\frac{1}{1000})^0(\frac{999}{1000})^2$  you will get a sum of 1 in this too.

Comment: You are using the symbol "$=$" for an approximation. Please stress the fact that this answer does not give the exact probabilities!

Comment: @Christoph:  Done!!

Comment: Why a downvote, I am introducing another way to look at the problem!!

Comment: I downvoted because this is not an answer to the question "Why do my probabilities do not sum up to $1$?"

Comment: Although it does not answer the question that the OP asked, it is still a valid answer to the problem posed by OP.  I am going to leave it even if  it receives further downvotes.

Comment: It is all about learning.  I bet he would not have thought of this from this angle.